# Redireccionar route con array en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, array, function, router

Quiero poder redireccionar a una ruta get de otro controlador, un $array que contiene id de registros. Pero no se como poder pasarlo de una ruta a otra o de ese controlador a este, para así poder usar ese array

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el controlador que contiene el $array

```
   public function CodesGetArray(Request $request, $array){

    $str_array = str_replace(array(","), "|", $array);

    $array_code = explode('|', $str_array);

    foreach ($array_code as $key => $id) {
        
        $check_array = array(
            'id' => $id,
        );

        $messagesArray[] = $check_array;
    }

    return dd($messagesArray);
    // return $check_array;
     
    // return redirect()->route('codes.validation.edit')->with('$messagesArray', $messagesArray);

   }
```

Y esta la route

```
 Route::get('codes-get-array/{array}', 'OrderCodesController@CodesGetArray')->name('codes.get.array');
```

Quiero poder pasarla esta variable $messagesArray a esta ruta:

```
Route::get('codes-validation-edit', 'OrderCodesController@CodesGetArrayEdit')->name('codes.validation.edit');
```

Que tiene este controlador:

```
   public function CodesGetArrayEdit(Request $request){

    return 'Hola';
    
   }
```

Me dijeron que por una return redirect()->route se podría pasar ese parámetro, pero no se como :c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que agregar la variable que vas a recibir por parámetro en la ruta a la cual vas  a redireccionar, como lo haces en **codes.get.array**

Algo asi:

```
Route::get('codes-validation-edit/{array}', 'OrderCodesController@CodesGetArrayEdit')->name('codes.validation.edit');
```

En tu controlador puedes redireccionarlo y pasarle el $array de las siguientes maneras:

```
return redirect()->route('codes.validation.edit', $messagesArray)

return redirect()->action('OrderCodesController@CodesGetArrayEdit', $messagesArray);
```

Comment: Gracias =) ya lo probare ;). Muchas gracias